# JavaScript getting all matching neighbors

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this:

```
const arr = [{
  label: [1,1]
},
{
  label: [1,0.5]
},
{
  label: [1,0.5]
}
,{
  label: [1,0.5]
}
,{
  label: [1,1]
}]
```

I then I have an index value, say that value is `2`. This would correspond to:

```
{
  label: [1,0.5]
}
```

Now, I want to find all indexes or objects that are next to this, based on the label value.  The way I'm doing the comparison is `label.join(',') ===` which is fine for this.

In this example array, there would be one before and one after the provided index of `2`.

I can iterate through, but not sure how to go "before or after", especially since there could be many before or many after.

This ended up working out well:

```
const index = 3;
const first = _.first(arr, index).reverse()
const rest = _.rest(arr, index + 1)
let found = []

for (let i = 0; first.length; i++) {
    if (first[i].label.join(',') == arr[index].label.join(',')) {
    found.push(first[i])
  } else {
    break;
  }
}

for (let i = 0; rest.length; i++) {
    if (rest[i].label.join(',') == arr[index].label.join(',')) {
    found.push(rest[i])
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: should it be a consequtive chain of neighbors?

Comment: What do you mean by "next to this"?

Comment: I do not get it. If idx ==2 then you have `arr[idx-1]` and `arr[idx+1]`

Comment: Can you explain what is the output you should get if index =4 for example?

Comment: If index = 4, it would be only that one, since it's at the end of the array and index 3 doesn't have have a matching value.

Comment: @mplungjan that's correct for this array, but what if there are more objects with matching labels in a row? I can't just do -1 or +1, there has to be some kind of iteration through the array to find matching labels.

Comment: @Barmar Next to this, refers to any object in the array that is before or after the index provided, where the label values match, however as soon as you run into a non-matching label, in other words is not sequential, it would end.

Answer (score 0):

Use loops that start from the given index and go forward and backward in the array.

After the loops you need to adjust the index that's found, because it ends when it finds a non-matching element.

```js
const array = [{
    label: [1, 1]
  },
  {
    label: [1, 0.5]
  },
  {
    label: [1, 0.5]
  }, {
    label: [1, 0.5]
  }, {
    label: [1, 1]
  }
];

const n = 2;
const label = array[n].label;
var start = n;
var end = n;
if (n > 0) {
  for (start = n - 1; start >= 0; start--) {
    if (array[start].label[0] != label[0] || array[start].label[1] != label[1]) {
      break;
    }
  }
  start++;
}
if (n < array.length - 1) {
  for (end = n + 1; end < array.length; end++) {
    if (array[end].label[0] != label[0] || array[end].label[1] != label[1]) {
      break;
    }
  }
  end--;
}
console.log(start, end);
```

Comment: thanks @Barmar I ended up using a similar solution i added to the question, this is close, but cleaned it up with lodash and can't check the index of the labels, need to check the full array value

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, not in the question.